# Is their any way i can define the properties in model so that my model can access those columns only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

Is their any way i can define the properties in model so that my model can access those columns only

let say we have a table employee as shown below

```
Employee
- Id
- Name
- Password
- Role
- CreatedDate
- EmailId
```

and we have two models as

```
class UserBasicInfo
Id integer
Name string
end

class UserLoginInfo
Id integer
Email string
Password string
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `default_scope` to only select those columns that you need

```
class UserBasicInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
   default_scope select("id, name")
end

class UserLoginInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select("id, email, password")
end
```